# Initiate TwentyTwenty.js after a div is shown thru a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm hiding a div until a button is clicked thru this script:

```
  $(document).ready(
      function() {
          $(".openthis").click(function() {
               $("#yalecontent").show("slow");
          });
      });
```

but I'm also using [TwentyTwenty](http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) inside that div and after I clicked the link to show the div, the TwentyTwenty content doesn't have any height so it's not showing up. How can I make it show up? This is my script for twenty twenty:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("#container1").twentytwenty();
  });
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/d4pj9yju/). Note that I can't make twentytwenty to work in here and I'm not sure why. It's working in my localhost but I just want to show how I made the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't hide '#yalecontent' div by css.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
  // hide here after twentytwenty load in this div.
  $("#yalecontent").hide("fast");

  $(".openthis").click(function() {
    $("#yalecontent").show("slow");
  });
});
```

Try this one it may be solve your problem.

Comment: There was one bug in chrome, only in chrome. On first reload, the twentytwenty container comes up, on second reload, it doesn't (height: 0px). here's my actual working page - http://www.mmoser.com/markl/yale/projects-yale3.html

Comment: which portion i have to check  ??

Comment: Just click the read all button and the div will appear but the height of the 2020 container height is 0.